# Stripe create customer function

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to implement the stripe create customer and save cards on my current reservation form. Currently it registers the payments but not the customers. I have tried implementing this https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards but had no luck.

Here is my plugin payment integration:

```
<?php
  
class CHBSPaymentStripe
{
    function __construct()
    {
 
    }
   
    function createPaymentForm($postId,$bookingId,$bookingTitle,$amount,$publishableKey)
    {
        $html=
        '
           <form action="'.get_the_permalink($postId).'?bookingId='.(int)$bookingId.'" method="POST" name="chbs-form-stripe" >
               <script
                   src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                    data-key="'.esc_attr($publishableKey).'"
                    data-allow-remember-me="true"
                    data-amount="'.esc_attr($amount*100).'"
                    data-name="'.esc_attr($bookingTitle).'"
                    data-description="'.esc_attr__('New booking','chauffeur-booking-system').'"
                    data-currency="'.esc_attr(CHBSOption::getOption('currency')).'"
                    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                    data-locale="auto">
                </script>
                <button type="submit" id="submitMeBtn" formtarget="_blank" style="display:none !important;"></button>
           </form>
        ';
       
        return($html);
    }
   
    function createCharge($stripeToken,$bookingId)
    {
        $Booking=new CHBSBooking();
        $BookingForm=new CHBSBookingForm();
       
        $booking=$Booking->getBooking($bookingId);
       
        if($booking===false) return(false);
       
        if($booking['meta']['payment_id']!=2) return(false);
       
        $bookingFormId=$booking['meta']['booking_form_id'];
       
        $bookingForm=$BookingForm->getDictionary(array('booking_form_id'=>$booking['meta']['booking_form_id']));
        if(count($bookingForm)!=1) return(false);
       
        $bookingBilling=$Booking->createBilling($bookingId);
       
        $data=array
        (
            'source'                                                            =>  $stripeToken,
            'description'                                                       =>  $booking['post']->post_title,
            'amount'                                                            =>  $bookingBilling['summary']['pay']*100,
            'currency'                                                          =>  $booking['meta']['currency_id']
        );
           
        $string=http_build_query($data);
       
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$bookingForm[$bookingFormId]['meta']['payment_stripe_api_key_secret']);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
           
        if($result)
        {
            $result=json_decode($result);
            if(property_exists($result,'error')) return(false);
 
            $meta=CHBSPostMeta::getPostMeta($bookingId);
               
            $paymentData=array
            (
                'txn_id'                                                        =>  $result->id,
                'payment_type'                                                  =>  $result->source->object,
                'payment_date'                                                  =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$result->created),
                'payment_status'                                                =>  $result->status,
                'mc_gross'                                                      =>  $result->amount/100,
                'mc_currency'                                                   =>  $result->currency        
            );
       
            if(!((array_key_exists('payment_data',$meta)) && (is_array($meta['payment_data']))))
                $meta['payment_data']=array();
       
            array_push($meta['payment_data'],$paymentData);
       
            CHBSPostMeta::updatePostMeta($bookingId,'payment_data',$meta['payment_data']);
           
            return(true);
        }
    }
   
    function redirect()
    {
        $bookingId=CHBSHelper::getGetValue('bookingId',false);
        $stripeToken=CHBSHelper::getPostValue('stripeToken',false);
       
        if($stripeToken!==null)
        {
            $PaymentStripe=new CHBSPaymentStripe();
            $PaymentStripe->createCharge($stripeToken,$bookingId);
           
            $Booking=new CHBSBooking();
            $BookingForm=new CHBSBookingForm();
           
            $Validation=new CHBSValidation();
           
            $booking=$Booking->getBooking($bookingId);
       
            $bookingFormId=$booking['meta']['booking_form_id'];
            if(($dictionary=$BookingForm->getDictionary(array('booking_fomr_id'=>$bookingFormId)))===false) return(false);
            if(count($dictionary)!=1) return(false);
       
            if($Validation->isNotEmpty($dictionary[$bookingFormId]['meta']['payment_stripe_redirect_url_address']))
            {
                wp_redirect($dictionary[$bookingFormId]['meta']['payment_stripe_redirect_url_address']);
                exit();
            }
        }          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any line in the code using customer endpoint.

In your case, you should create a customer first, store the card details for that customer and then charge the customer.

Check out [this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=php) API library by stripe to create a customer. I would recommend you to use this Stripe library for PHP. I am using Stripe with Python and this library help avoiding many errors.